# General Form for Intersection of Quadratic with Natural Log Function

Tags: quadratics, lambert-w

Given $x. a_0, a_1, a_2, b\in\mathbb{R}$ is there a general solution to the equation:

$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2=b\ln(x)$

I am aware of the connection between this sort of equation and the Lambert W function, but have not been able to find a generic solution.

Comment: you could try completing the square on the left, transferring some terms to the right to obtain $(f(x))^2 = k\ln(g(x))$, then use Lambert W.

Comment: In general wouldn't that reduce to the form $(f(x))^2 + c = k\ln(g(x))$?

Comment: $c = \ln(e^c)$, which you can move to RHS and get $k\ln(g(x)/e^{c/k})$